# Plotting graphs with strings instead of values in the x-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I was trying to get some complex graphs into latex from raw data (as seen in the first figure) but I have no idea on how to code that into latex. The main problem I'm encountering is that I can't manage to properly read the data so that latex plots it properly. That is because the x-axis doesn't have actual values, as it can be seen in the second picture.

Any ideas on how to get this to work? Thanks!

[image: What I'd like my plot to look like]

[image: data file for one of the lines]

Comment: Without posting your code, it could be anyone's guess as to what you are trying and how to revise it.  Is it even LaTeX?

Comment: The second picture seems to show x-values and y-values.

Comment: Assuming you're using `pgfplots`, you might be after `symbolic x coords`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure, if I understand the question. But maybe you are looking for something like

```
\begin{filecontents*}{exampledata.dat}
1 1,1 1.05
2 1,2 1.1
3 text 1.5
4 3,5 0.9
5 3,6 1.3
6 4,2 0.8
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}% loads also pgfplots
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14} 
\pgfplotstableread[
    display columns/1/.style=string type,
    header=false
  ]{exampledata.dat}{\loadeddata}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \begin{axis}[
      xtick={0,2,...,100},% row numbers for ticks
      xticklabel={%
        \pgfmathsetmacro\rowindex{int(\tick)}% row index must be an integer
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\rowindex}{[index]1}\of\loadeddata% get the string from the loaded table
        \pgfplotsretval% print the resulting ticklabel
      },
    ]
    \addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y index=2]\loadeddata;
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: The OP will have to clarify, but I wonder if e.g. `8,29` are *two* numbers, used as identifiers for e.g. simulations, or experiment setups.

Comment: I have concluded from the picture in the question that `8,29`could be a number with a comma as decimal mark. But of course I can be wrong ...

Comment: Not that likely, considering that the distance from e.g. 7,31 to 7,34 in the plot is the same as from 7,34 to 8,21.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You are right. I have changed my answer.

Comment: Thanks guys, you're the best, you solved it! And sorry for not posting the code. I had no idea how to approach it with strings, I should've still tried and posted some code regardless. The numbers "7,29" and etc are indeed **two** numbers, used as identifiers (settings) from an iterative program. @esdd

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks! The numbers "7,29" and etc are indeed two numbers, used as identifiers (settings) from an iterative program.